$Out(F_n)$ has a free abelian subgroup of rank $2n-3$
Proposition 9.5.4 The group $Out(F_n)$ has a free abelian subgroup of rank $2n-3$.
This is a proposition of the book "Topological Methotods in Group Theory" by R. Geoghegan. In the proof he just says to consider the automorphisms $y_i \mapsto y_1y_i$ and $y_i \mapsto y_iy_1$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$ where $y_1,...,y_n$ are the free generators of $F_n$.
If $A$ is the group generated by these automorphisms, I can see that it is a free abelian subgroup of rank $2n-2$ in $Aut(F_n)$. So, I suppose that the image of $A$ in $Out(F_n)$ is of rank $2n-3$, but I don't know how justify it.

First you say "index", then you say "rank".

Let me use the notation
$$L_i : \begin{cases} 
y_i &\mapsto y_1 y_i \\ 
y_j &\mapsto y_j \quad\text{if $j \ne i$}
\end{cases}
$$
$$R_i : \begin{cases}
y_i &\mapsto y_i y_1 \\
y_j &\mapsto y_j \quad\text{if $j \ne i$}
\end{cases}
$$
So we can think of $\{L_1,...,L_{n-1},R_1,\ldots,R_{n-1}\}$ as a basis for
$\mathbb Z^{2n-2}$, and the formulas above define a homomorphism
$$H : \mathbb Z^{2n-2} \mapsto \text{Out}(F_n)
$$
Here's an element of the kernel of $H$:
$$T = L^{\vphantom{-1}}_1 \, R^{-1}_1 L^{\vphantom{-1}}_2 \,  \, R^{-1}_2 \cdots \, L^{\vphantom{-1}}_{n-1} \, R^{-1}_{n-1}
$$
This satisfies the formula $y_i \mapsto y_1 y_i y^{-1}_1$ for all $i=1,...,n$ and is therefore an inner automorphism of the group $F_n$, namely $\gamma \mapsto y_1 \gamma y^{-1}_1$ for all $\gamma \in F_n$. So $T$ represents the identity element of the outer automorphism group $\text{Out}(F_n)$.
It should be clear that $T$ is a basis element of $\mathbb Z^{2n-2}$; because the equation $T=\text{Id}$ can be solved for $L_1$.
All that remains is to show that $T$ generates the kernel of $H$. Take any element $S \in H$ and write it in the form
$$S = L_1^{a_1}  \, R_1^{-b_1}  \, L_2^{a_2}  \, R_2^{-b_2}  \, \cdots L_{n-1}^{a_{n-1}} \, R_{n-1}^{-b_{n-1}}
$$
Consider the exponent sequence $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...,a_{n-1},b_{n-1}$ and ask the question:

What happens when this sequence is not constant?

Assuming that happens, one must prove that $S$ is not an inner automorphism of $F_n$, and we'll be done.
An easy case is when $a_i \ne b_i$ for some $i \in \{1,...,n-1\}$, in which case $S(y_i)$ is not conjugate to $y_i$ in $F_n$, and therefore $S$ is not an inner automorphism of $F_n$
We can therefore assume that $a_i = b_i$ for all $i$, and that there exist $i \ne j \in \{1,...,n-1\}$ such that $a_i=b_i \ne a_j=b_j$. In this case one observes that $S(y_iy_j)$ is not conjugate to $y_iy_j$ and so again $S$ is not an inner automorphism.

Nice! I tried a few times find a relation to discard some of these automorphisms in $Out(F_n)$ but I could not.

It helps to think topologically, i.e. to consider the pointed homotopy equivalences of the rank $n$ rose represented by those generators. That's how I visualized it, anyway, to come up with the formula for $T$.

This is interesting. Could you explain the idea? I still cannot naturally visualize this type of argument.

Perhaps that could be a topic for a different post. But I would suggest further reading. The geometric point of view on $\text{Out}(F_n)$ is prominent in papers of Gersten and Stallings, and in the topic of train track representatives of outer automorphisms starting with work of Bestvina and Handel.

Great answer! Perhaps a slightly easier way to see $T$ generates the kernel is to note that $H\cap Inn(F_n)$ is both a free and free Abelian subgroup, so can only be trivial or cyclic.

Oh! I like that @SteveD.
